# sameformfieldsasarray in Application.cfm

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, application.cfm

I am working on a Legacy Application and they are using Application.cfm, now that file cannot be converted to Application.cfc due to the fact that the site is too big and probably making a change will make it unstable

In one of the Pages, I have defined the form field as: `keys[]` to return me an array. I have defined the

```
<cfset this.sameformfieldsasarray = "true">
```

in Application.cfm under the `cfapplication` tag

But that does not seems to be working, it just creates the list rather than an array.

So Question is:

1. How can i use that function?
2. If i cannot use that function in Application.cfm, is there any other way to use it in The Page only where I need to the form value as an array

i am using coldfusion Version 11

Comment: Try running `<cfdump var="#form#">` See if it is doing anything interesting

Comment: Just using `[]` in the field name does not create an array. Using the same name (any name) for multiple form fields AND using the `sameFormFieldsAsArray` attribute in your Application file. However, AFAIK it only works for Application.cfc. Assuming a "list" will not work, is there a reason you cannot just dynamically name the fields, ie key_1, key_2, key_3, etcetera?

Comment: its because of bad design being followed, i can't change it, too much

Comment: Please elaborate on, `In one of the Pages, I have defined the form field as: keys[] to return me an array`.

Comment: This means that in my Application.cfc i had used the this.sameformfieldasarray to set true so when i use that keys[] notation, it should return me that. To be clear, I tested the same on Lucee and it worked

Comment: Given that it probably does not work in ACF, you may need to find another approach. What about the question above? *Assuming a "list" will not work, is there a reason you cannot just dynamically name the fields, ie key_1, key_2, key_3, etcetera?*

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting the value to be a string rather than a boolean

```
<cfset this.sameformfieldsasarray = "true">
```

Should be

```
<cfset this.sameformfieldsasarray = true>
```

Also consider using `application.cfc`

Comment: i tried both, but that does seems to do any change and even i dumped the form scope, it did not did anything, is it something related to to the application scope reinit, btw it is a this scope and that is local scope, i do not think it needs such. i can't try this code in trycf because it does not let me run the code there

Comment: James - Pretty sure Application.cfm does not support 'sameformfieldsasarray", only cfc.

Comment: So it is a BUG then

Comment: Since Application.cfm files are now discouraged, in favor of Application.cfc, it could also be they just decided not to implement newer features in the cfapplication tag.

Comment: then adobe is just foolish

Comment: If you think it should be supported, [file a bug report](https://bugbase.adobe.com/). Otherwise, if you are looking for an alternative, you need to answer [the earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218878/sameformfieldsasarray-in-application-cfm#comment75469472_44218878).

Answer (score 0):

OP's mistake was in trying to set that `sameformfieldsasarray` setting via a `cfset` of the `this` scope AFTER ("under") the `cfapplication` they had. That would be appropriate only in an `application.cfc`. When using `application.cfm` instead, they should have simply set it as an **attribute** of the `cfapplication` tag:

`<cfapplication sameformfieldsasarray="true">` (or false, if desired)

Sadly, most docs and resources mentioning this `sameformfieldsasarray` feature (and other features that can be set in the `this` scope of an `application.cfc`) tend to not mention how nearly all of them can be set as attributes of `cfapplication` as well.